# Selecting rows in dataframe until a condition is met and stop the loop- Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a txt file that has more than 8k rows, have managed to clean it and now i want to loop through the whole data to split it into two excel sheets. Category A and Category B. I want to loop and select rows and once  meet a row that contains some string, once this key word is met on the first occurrence the looping should stop and the result exported to excel

I have tried using for loop in checking the rows i want and dropping the ones i don't want but the similar rows from another appear in all categories...
sample data

```
NUM DATE  TIME     TARD NUMBER         REF NUMBER   NUMBER TRMNL/NAME  TYPE CODE   MOD CODE STP CD        AMOUNT CUR   AMOUNT (A) 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  40 10NOV 06:57:36 4634050200885367    657406041760 041760 746842      0200 012000 051      02  00     25,000.00 KES       205.42CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ06101  TA10000XYZ06101        25/SRA NAROK                /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
  41 10NOV 07:07:38 4580160118732868    657407041761 041761 458016      0200 010000 051      02  00     14,900.00 KES       122.43CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ02001  TA10001XYZ02001        25/XYZ DIANI                /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
  41 10NOV 07:10:25 4318711071280219    657407041764 041764 431871      0200 010000 051      02  00      3,000.00 KES        24.65CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ00803  TA10001XYZ00803        25/SRA ONN THE WAY LMR RD   /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
                                                                                                                           
  42 10NOV 07:30:21 4863480011789758    657407041773 041773 486348      0200 300000 051      00  00          0.00 KES         0.00   
                    TA ID: XYZ01101  TA10000XYZ01101        25/SRA MALINDI              /ED  0000                                    
                                                                                                                                 
  42 10NOV 07:31:06 HHHH060000359699    657407041774 041774 HHHH06      0200 300000 051      00  06          0.00 KES         0.00   
                    TA ID: XYZ03201  TA10000XYZ03201        25/SRA VOI                  /ED  0000                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  42 10NOV 07:57:07 4221740021146317    657407041781 041781 422174      0200 010000 051      02  00     40,000.00 KES       328.68CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ02001  TA10001XYZ02001        25/XYZ DIANI                /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
  43 10NOV 08:10:50 4036490000012644    657408041784 041784 403649      0200 010000 051      02  51     20,000.00 KES         0.00   
                    TA ID: XYZ04301  TA10000XYZ04301        25/SRA LAMU                 /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
  
  VAT XMIT(GMT)/LOCL                     RETRIEVAL    TRACE  SENDER ID/  SRAM PROCSS ENT REAS CN/ RSP      --ACTION--   SETTLEMENT   
  NUM DATE  TIME     TARD NUMBER         REF NUMBER   NUMBER TRMNL/NAME  TYPE CODE   MOD CODE STP CD        AMOUNT CUR   AMOUNT (A) 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  44 11NOV 06:57:36 4634050200885367    657406041760 041760 746842      0200 012000 051      02  00     25,000.00 KES       205.42CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ06101  TA10000XYZ06101        25/SRA NAROK                /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
  44 11NOV 07:07:38 4580160118732868    657407041761 041761 458016      0200 010000 051      02  00     14,900.00 KES       122.43CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ02001  TA10001XYZ02001        25/XYZ DIANI                /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
  45 11NOV 07:18:35 4930005028593164    657407041769 041769 493000      0200 010000 051      02  00     40,000.00 KES       328.68CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ04201  TA10000XYZ04201        25/SRA MTWAPA               /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
                                                                                                                              
  45 11NOV 07:19:29 4930005028593164    657407041770 041770 493000      0200 010000 051      02  00     30,000.00 KES       246.51CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ04201  TA10000XYZ04201        25/SRA MTWAPA               /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
  46 11NOV 07:30:21 4863480011789758    657407041773 041773 486348      0200 300000 051      00  00          0.00 KES         0.00   
                    TA ID: XYZ01101  TA10000XYZ01101        25/SRA MALINDI              /ED  0000                                    
                                                                                                                                 
  46 11NOV 07:31:06 HHHH060000359699    657407041774 041774 HHHH06      0200 300000 051      00  06          0.00 KES         0.00   
                    TA ID: XYZ03201  TA10000XYZ03201        25/SRA VOI                  /ED  0000                                    
                                                                                                                                 
  47 11NOV 07:38:05 4034910028476291    657407041777 041777 403491      0200 012000 051      02  00     40,000.00 KES       328.68CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ01401  TA10000XYZ01401        25/SRA ELDORET              /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
                                                                                                                                       
  47 11NOV 07:38:35 HHHH060000359699    657407041778 041778 HHHH06      0200 300000 051      00  06          0.00 KES         0.00   
                    TA ID: XYZ03201  TA10000XYZ03201        25/SRA VOI                  /ED  0000                                    
                                                                                                                             
  48 11NOV 07:57:07 4221740021146317    657407041781 041781 422174      0200 010000 051      02  00     40,000.00 KES       328.68CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ02001  TA10001XYZ02001        25/XYZ DIANI                /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
  48 11NOV 08:10:50 4036490000012644    657408041784 041784 403649      0200 010000 051      02  51     20,000.00 KES         0.00   
                    TA ID: XYZ04301  TA10000XYZ04301        25/SRA LAMU                 /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
  
  VAT XMIT(GMT)/LOCL                     RETRIEVAL    TRACE  SENDER ID/  SRAM PROCSS ENT REAS CN/ RSP      --ACTION--   SETTLEMENT   
NUM DATE  TIME     TARD NUMBER         REF NUMBER   NUMBER TRMNL/NAME  TYPE CODE   MOD CODE STP CD        AMOUNT CUR   AMOUNT (A) 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  49 14NOV 06:57:36 4634050200885367    657406041760 041760 746842      0200 012000 051      02  00     25,000.00 KES       205.42CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ06101  TA10000XYZ06101        25/SRA NAROK                /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
  49 14NOV 07:07:38 4580160118732868    657407041761 041761 458016      0200 010000 051      02  00     14,900.00 KES       122.43CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ02001  TA10001XYZ02001        25/XYZ DIANI                /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
  50 14NOV 07:30:21 4863480011789758    657407041773 041773 486348      0200 300000 051      00  00          0.00 KES         0.00   
                    TA ID: XYZ01101  TA10000XYZ01101        25/SRA MALINDI              /ED  0000                                    
                                                                                                                                 
  50 14NOV 07:31:06 HHHH060000359699    657407041774 041774 HHHH06      0200 300000 051      00  06          0.00 KES         0.00   
                    TA ID: XYZ03201  TA10000XYZ03201        25/SRA VOI                  /ED  0000                                    
                                                                                                                                 
  50 14NOV 07:55:26 4221740021146317    657407041780 041780 422174      0200 010000 051      02  00      6,000.00 KES        49.30CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ02001  TA10001XYZ02001        25/XYZ DIANI                /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
                                                                                                                                
  50 14NOV 07:57:07 4221740021146317    657407041781 041781 422174      0200 010000 051      02  00     40,000.00 KES       328.68CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ02001  TA10001XYZ02001        25/XYZ DIANI                /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
  50 10NOV 08:10:50 4036490000012644    657408041784 041784 403649      0200 010000 051      02  51     20,000.00 KES         0.00   
                    TA ID: XYZ04301  TA10000XYZ04301        25/SRA LAMU                 /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
  
  VAT XMIT(GMT)/LOCL                     RETRIEVAL    TRACE  SENDER ID/  SRAM PROCSS ENT REAS CN/ RSP      --ACTION--   SETTLEMENT   
  NUM DATE  TIME     TARD NUMBER         REF NUMBER   NUMBER TRMNL/NAME  TYPE CODE   MOD CODE STP CD        AMOUNT CUR   AMOUNT (A) 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  51 15NOV 06:57:36 4634050200885367    657406041760 041760 746842      0200 012000 051      02  00     25,000.00 KES       205.42CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ06101  TA10000XYZ06101        25/SRA NAROK                /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
  51 15NOV 07:07:38 4580160118732868    657407041761 041761 458016      0200 010000 051      02  00     14,900.00 KES       122.43CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ02001  TA10001XYZ02001        25/XYZ DIANI                /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
  51 15NOV 07:10:25 4318711071280219    657407041764 041764 431871      0200 010000 051      02  00      3,000.00 KES        24.65CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ00803  TA10001XYZ00803        25/SRA ONN THE WAY LMR RD   /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
                                                                                                                           
  52 15NOV 07:18:35 4930005028593164    657407041769 041769 493000      0200 010000 051      02  00     40,000.00 KES       328.68CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ04201  TA10000XYZ04201        25/SRA MTWAPA               /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  52 15NOV 07:21:20 4922950014377066    657407041772 041772 492295      0200 010000 051      02  00     30,000.00 KES       246.51CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ04301  TA10000XYZ04301        25/SRA LAMU                 /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
  53 15NOV 07:30:21 4863480011789758    657407041773 041773 486348      0200 300000 051      00  00          0.00 KES         0.00   
                    TA ID: XYZ01101  TA10000XYZ01101        25/SRA MALINDI              /ED  0000                                    
  53 15NOV 07:38:05 4034910028476291    657407041777 041777 403491      0200 012000 051      02  00     40,000.00 KES       328.68CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ01401  TA10000XYZ01401        25/SRA ELDORET              /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
                                                                                                                                       
  54 15NOV 07:38:35 HHHH060000359699    657407041778 041778 HHHH06      0200 300000 051      00  06          0.00 KES         0.00   
                    TA ID: XYZ03201  TA10000XYZ03201        25/SRA VOI                  /ED  0000                                    
                                                                                                                                
  54 11NOV 08:10:50 4036490000012644    657408041784 041784 403649      0200 010000 051      02  51     20,000.00 KES         0.00   
                    TA ID: XYZ04301  TA10000XYZ04301        25/SRA LAMU                 /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
  VAT XMIT(GMT)/LOCL                     RETRIEVAL    TRACE  SENDER ID/  SRAM PROCSS ENT REAS CN/ RSP      --ACTION--   SETTLEMENT   
NUM DATE  TIME     TARD NUMBER         REF NUMBER   NUMBER TRMNL/NAME  TYPE CODE   MOD CODE STP CD        AMOUNT CUR   AMOUNT (B) 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  40 10OCT 06:57:36 4634050200885367    657406041760 041760 746842      0200 012000 051      02  00     25,000.00 KES       205.42CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ06101  TA10000XYZ06101        25/SRA NAROK                /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
  41 10OCT 07:07:38 4580160118732868    657407041761 041761 458016      0200 010000 051      02  00     14,900.00 KES       122.43CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ02001  TA10001XYZ02001        25/XYZ DIANI                /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  41 10OCT 07:21:20 4922950014377066    657407041772 041772 492295      0200 010000 051      02  00     30,000.00 KES       246.51CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ04301  TA10000XYZ04301        25/SRA LAMU                 /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
  42 10OCT 07:30:21 4863480011789758    657407041773 041773 486348      0200 300000 051      00  00          0.00 KES         0.00   
                    TA ID: XYZ01101  TA10000XYZ01101        25/SRA MALINDI              /ED  0000                                    
                                                                                                                                 
  42 10OCT 07:31:06 HHHH060000359699    657407041774 041774 HHHH06      0200 300000 051      00  06          0.00 KES         0.00   
                    TA ID: XYZ03201  TA10000XYZ03201        25/SRA VOI                  /ED  0000                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  42 10OCT 07:57:07 4221740021146317    657407041781 041781 422174      0200 010000 051      02  00     40,000.00 KES       328.68CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ02001  TA10001XYZ02001        25/XYZ DIANI                /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
  43 10OCT 08:10:50 4036490000012644    657408041784 041784 403649      0200 010000 051      02  51     20,000.00 KES         0.00   
                    TA ID: XYZ04301  TA10000XYZ04301        25/SRA LAMU                 /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
  
  VAT XMIT(GMT)/LOCL                     RETRIEVAL    TRACE  SENDER ID/  SRAM PROCSS ENT REAS CN/ RSP      --ACTION--   SETTLEMENT   
  NUM DATE  TIME     TARD NUMBER         REF NUMBER   NUMBER TRMNL/NAME  TYPE CODE   MOD CODE STP CD        AMOUNT CUR   AMOUNT (B) 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  44 18OCT 06:57:36 4634050200885367    657406041760 041760 746842      0200 012000 051      02  00     25,000.00 KES       205.42CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ06101  TA10000XYZ06101        25/SRA NAROK                /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
  44 18OCT 07:07:38 4580160118732868    657407041761 041761 458016      0200 010000 051      02  00     14,900.00 KES       122.43CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ02001  TA10001XYZ02001        25/XYZ DIANI                /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
                                                                                                                             
  45 18OCT 07:20:00 4906385159141011    657407041771 041771 490638      0200 010000 051      02  00     25,000.00 KES       205.42CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ02701  TA10000XYZ02701        25/XYZ KAKAMEGA             /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
                                                                                                                                 
  45 18OCT 07:21:20 4922950014377066    657407041772 041772 492295      0200 010000 051      02  00     30,000.00 KES       246.51CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ04301  TA10000XYZ04301        25/SRA LAMU                 /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
  46 18OCT 07:30:21 4863480011789758    657407041773 041773 486348      0200 300000 051      00  00          0.00 KES         0.00   
                    TA ID: XYZ01101  TA10000XYZ01101        25/SRA MALINDI              /ED  0000                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  46 18OCT 07:31:46 HHHH060000359699    657407041775 041775 HHHH06      0200 300000 051      00  06          0.00 KES         0.00   
                    TA ID: XYZ03201  TA10000XYZ03201        25/SRA VOI                  /ED  0000                                    
  47 18OCT 07:38:05 4034910028476291    657407041777 041777 403491      0200 012000 051      02  00     40,000.00 KES       328.68CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ01401  TA10000XYZ01401        25/SRA ELDORET              /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
                                                                                                                                       
  47 18OCT 07:38:35 HHHH060000359699    657407041778 041778 HHHH06      0200 300000 051      00  06          0.00 KES         0.00   
                    TA ID: XYZ03201  TA10000XYZ03201        25/SRA VOI                  /ED  0000                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  48 18OCT 07:57:07 4221740021146317    657407041781 041781 422174      0200 010000 051      02  00     40,000.00 KES       328.68CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ02001  TA10001XYZ02001        25/XYZ DIANI                /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
  48 18OCT 08:10:50 4036490000012644    657408041784 041784 403649      0200 010000 051      02  51     20,000.00 KES         0.00   
                    TA ID: XYZ04301  TA10000XYZ04301        25/SRA LAMU                 /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
  
  VAT XMIT(GMT)/LOCL                     RETRIEVAL    TRACE  SENDER ID/  SRAM PROCSS ENT REAS CN/ RSP      --ACTION--   SETTLEMENT   
NUM DATE  TIME     TARD NUMBER         REF NUMBER   NUMBER TRMNL/NAME  TYPE CODE   MOD CODE STP CD        AMOUNT CUR   AMOUNT (B) 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  49 13SEP 06:57:36 4634050200885367    657406041760 041760 746842      0200 012000 051      02  00     25,000.00 KES       205.42CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ06101  TA10000XYZ06101        25/SRA NAROK                /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
  49 13SEP 07:07:38 4580160118732868    657407041761 041761 458016      0200 010000 051      02  00     14,900.00 KES       122.43CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ02001  TA10001XYZ02001        25/XYZ DIANI                /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
                                                                                                                                
  49 13SEP 07:21:20 4922950014377066    657407041772 041772 492295      0200 010000 051      02  00     30,000.00 KES       246.51CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ04301  TA10000XYZ04301        25/SRA LAMU                 /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
  50 13SEP 07:30:21 4863480011789758    657407041773 041773 486348      0200 300000 051      00  00          0.00 KES         0.00   
                    TA ID: XYZ01101  TA10000XYZ01101        25/SRA MALINDI              /ED  0000                                    
                                                                                                                                 
  50 13SEP 07:31:06 HHHH060000359699    657407041774 041774 HHHH06      0200 300000 051      00  06          0.00 KES         0.00   
                    TA ID: XYZ03201  TA10000XYZ03201        25/SRA VOI                  /ED  0000                                    
                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                      
  50 13SEP 07:38:35 HHHH060000359699    657407041778 041778 HHHH06      0200 300000 051      00  06          0.00 KES         0.00   
                    TA ID: XYZ03201  TA10000XYZ03201        25/SRA VOI                  /ED  0000                                    
                                                                                                                                
  50 13SEP 07:55:26 4221740021146317    657407041780 041780 422174      0200 010000 051      02  00      6,000.00 KES        49.30CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ02001  TA10001XYZ02001        25/XYZ DIANI                /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
 
  VAT XMIT(GMT)/LOCL                     RETRIEVAL    TRACE  SENDER ID/  SRAM PROCSS ENT REAS CN/ RSP      --ACTION--   SETTLEMENT   
  NUM DATE  TIME     TARD NUMBER         REF NUMBER   NUMBER TRMNL/NAME  TYPE CODE   MOD CODE STP CD        AMOUNT CUR   AMOUNT (B) 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  51 15NOV 06:57:36 4634050200885367    657406041760 041760 746842      0200 012000 051      02  00     25,000.00 KES       205.42CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ06101  TA10000XYZ06101        25/SRA NAROK                /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
  51 15NOV 07:07:38 4580160118732868    657407041761 041761 458016      0200 010000 051      02  00     14,900.00 KES       122.43CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ02001  TA10001XYZ02001        25/XYZ DIANI                /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
  51 15NOV 07:10:25 4318711071280219    657407041764 041764 431871      0200 010000 051      02  00      3,000.00 KES        24.65CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ00803  TA10001XYZ00803        25/SRA ONN THE WAY LMR RD   /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  52 15NOV 07:20:00 4906385159141011    657407041771 041771 490638      0200 010000 051      02  00     25,000.00 KES       205.42CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ02701  TA10000XYZ02701        25/XYZ KAKAMEGA             /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
                                                                                                                                 
  52 15NOV 07:21:20 4922950014377066    657407041772 041772 492295      0200 010000 051      02  00     30,000.00 KES       246.51CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ04301  TA10000XYZ04301        25/SRA LAMU                 /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  54 15NOV 07:38:35 HHHH060000359699    657407041778 041778 HHHH06      0200 300000 051      00  06          0.00 KES         0.00   
                    TA ID: XYZ03201  TA10000XYZ03201        25/SRA VOI                  /ED  0000                                    
                                                                                                                                
  54 15NOV 07:55:26 4221740021146317    657407041780 041780 422174      0200 010000 051      02  00      6,000.00 KES        49.30CR 
                    TA ID: XYZ02001  TA10001XYZ02001        25/XYZ DIANI                /ED  0000                  FPI: 8C1          
  
[here is code snippet][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TW1cl.png
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Added sample data and code

Comment: Can you please give an example of a key word and which column/s (perhaps all columns?) should be checked for the key word?

Comment: @constantstranger when this data is converted to df it has only one column, so am checking if some key words are in a row. e.g "Amount (A)" and the loop should stop in it meets a keyword " AMOUNT (B)" in a row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long long and critical thinking on this i finally figured outon ow to circumnavigate on this..
first find all the occurrences of the keyword
second, push the all the occurrences to a list `list=[], list.append(x)`
extract the first item from the lisst and use it and row index to stop at. `varx=list[0]` will get you the 1st item which is an int.
thirdly, use `iloc()` to truncate. the `varx` will be the ending point for slicing or the start point : acording to your needs. i.e `iloc[:varx]` or `iloc[varx:`]
finally export to excel as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your text file has been converted to a pandas dataframe and the key word is expected to be found in a particular column named `a`, you can do something like this to split the input dataframe into two outputs:

```py
import pandas as pd
keyWord = 'foo'
df = pd.DataFrame({
'a':['bar' for _ in range(4)] + [keyWord] + ['baz' for _ in range(3)],
'b':range(8)
})
print('input', df, sep='\n')
found = (df.a == keyWord).cumsum().shift(fill_value=0)
print('first sheet', df[found == 0], sep='\n')
print('second sheet', df[found > 0], sep='\n')
```

Sample output:

```
input
     a  b
0  bar  0
1  bar  1
2  bar  2
3  bar  3
4  foo  4
5  baz  5
6  baz  6
7  baz  7
first sheet
     a  b
0  bar  0
1  bar  1
2  bar  2
3  bar  3
4  foo  4
second sheet
     a  b
5  baz  5
6  baz  6
7  baz  7
```

Explanation:

- compare the value in each row's column `a` with the key word.
- use [`cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) to count these; for rows prior to the first occurrence of the key word, `cumsum` will give 0, and starting with the first matching row, it will give a number > 0.
- use [`shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to move the results of `cumsum` downward by one row; this will cause the first matching row to be kept with the first sheet rather than the second sheet.

Note:

- If instead you want the first row containing the key word to be in the second sheet, you can remove `shift` from the initialization of `found` like this:

```py
found = (df.a == keyWord).cumsum()
```